# How to set Postgres roles on CircleCI 2.0

Tags: postgresql, circleci

I followed the directions here:
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/postgres-config/

And my relevant Circle config looks like this:

```
test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:6.11.0
      - image: circleci/mongo:3.2.13
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.5
        environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=custom
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
        - POSTGRES_DB=custom
      - image: rabbitmq:3.5.4
    steps:
    etc etc...
```

But I am getting the following error when I try to connect on my nodejs app on `localhost:5432`:

`error: error during connection: SequelizeConnectionError: FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist`

Why is it even trying to use "ubuntu" if I've defined `POSTGRES_USER=custom`?

This doesn't work if I remove my environment vars either. And I don't understand why that's not working, because it should default to ubuntu according to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Your config file doesn't look quite right. This is what the usual format is.

```
version: 2.0
jobs:
  build:
  docker:
    - image: circleci/node:6.11.0
    - image: circleci/postgres:9.5
      environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=custom_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=custom_password
      - POSTGRES_DB=custom_db

  working_directory: ~/your_project_dir

  steps:
   - 
   -
   ..
```

After this, check if the db-user, password and database name is same the one mentioned in environment block above. You might need to double check your values in code and `.env` files.

`jdbc:postgresql://localhost/custom_db?user=custom_user&password=custom_pass`

If you're using ruby or node, you might have to set your ruby-env's/node's variables.